# Prove that $6|a+b+c$ if and only if $6|a^3+b^3+c^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$6=2\cdot3$

$a^3+b^3+c^3 = (a+b+c)^3-3(a^2b+ab^2)-3(a+b)^2-3(a+b)c$

So it's divisible by $3$, what about $2$?

Comment: $a^3-a=(a-1)a(a+1).$  At least 1 of the   3 consecutive integers $a-1,a,a+1$ is even.  So $a^3-a$ is even. So $(a^3+b^3+c^3)-(a+b+c)$ is even. Therefore :  $a^3+b^3+c^3$ is even iff $a+b+c$ is even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Hint:

$$a^3+b^3+c^3-(a+b+c)=(a^3-a)+(b^3-b)+(c^3-c)$$

But $6|n^3-n=(n-1)n(n+1)$

Answer (score 0):

By Fermat's little theorem, we have $x^3\equiv x\pmod3$ for every $x$, and of course, $x^3\equiv x\pmod2$. This means that
$$ a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv a+b+c\pmod3$$
and
$$ a^3+b^3+c^3\equiv a+b+c\pmod2,$$
which was what we wanted.

Comment: Wait how is $x^3\equiv x\pmod2$?

Comment: If $x\equiv 0\pmod2$, then $x^3\equiv 0^3\equiv 0\pmod 2$. If $x\equiv 1\pmod 2$, then we get $x^3\equiv 1^3\equiv 1\pmod2$.